# Error In Saving appointment task for Windows Phone 8.1(Value does not fall within the expected range)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, appointment

Below is the Code, I used to save the appointment task for Windows Phone 8.1.

```
private async void Add-Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create an Appointment that should be added the user's appointments provider app.
    var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();

    appointment.StartTime = timeconversion.AddMinutes(-10);
    appointment.Location = sharingProgramTime; // appointment location
    appointment.Subject = sharingProgramName; // appointment subject
    appointment.Details = sharingProgramName  + sharingProgramTime; // appointment details
    appointment.IsAllDayEvent = false;
    appointment.Reminder = new TimeSpan(0,10,0); // Ten minutes
    appointment.BusyStatus = AppointmentBusyStatus.Busy;

    // Get the selection rect of the button pressed to add this appointment
    var rect = GetElementRect(sender as FrameworkElement);

    // ShowAddAppointmentAsync returns an appointment id if the appointment given was added to the user's calendar.
    // This value should be stored in app data and roamed so that the appointment can be replaced or removed in the future.
    // An empty string return value indicates that the user canceled the operation before the appointment was added.
    String appointmentId = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(
                           appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
}
```

I can save the appointment in the calendar for the first time. In the last execution of the below code,

```
String appointmentId = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(
                           appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
```

The app get crash due to the following error, **Value does not fall within the expected range**

Please guide me to resolve the issue

Thank you